# Parsing percent expressions with antlr4

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse algebraic expressions with ANTLR4. One feature I tried to accomplish with my parser is the "intelligent" handling of percent expressions.

**Edit:** The goal is to make the calculation of discounts or tips in a restaurant easier. E.g. if you see an advert "30% off" you could enter "price - 30%" and get the correct result. Or in a restaurant you could enter the price of your meal plus 15% and get the sum you have to pay including a tip of 15%. But this interpretation should only occur if the expression looks like "expression1 (- or +) expression2". In all other cases the percent sign should be interpreted as usual. The Google Search box calculator behaves like that.**/Edit**

`100-30%` should return *70*
`100-(20+10)%` should also return *70*
`3+(100-(20+10)%)` should return *73*
**but**
`5%` should return *0.05*
`(5+5)%` should return *0.10*

My grammar looks like this:

```
expr:
 e EOF   
;

e:
   '-'a=e                          
 | '(' a=e ')'                     
 | a=e op=(ADD|SUB) b=e '%'        
 | a=e op=(ADD|SUB) b=e            
 | a=e'%'                          //**PERCENTRULE**
 | FLT                             
 ;

ADD :  '+' ;
SUB :  '-' ;
FLT: [0-9]+(('.'|',')[0-9]+)?;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
WS : [ \t\n]+ -> skip ;
```

For the expression `100-30%` I would **expect** the this tree:
[image: Expected parse tree for the expression "100-30%"]

But I get this:
[image: parse tree for the expression "100-30%]
How can I get the correct tree (without deleting PERCENTRULE)?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my original grammar-based answer because I realized I had a very different idea of what kind of handling you were trying to accomplish. It sounds like you want anything in the form `X op Y %` to become `X * (1 op (Y/100))` instead. Is that accurate?

> One feature I tried to accomplish with my parser is the "intelligent" handling of percent expressions:

Are you sure your specification for this is solid enough to even begin coding? It looks quite confusing to me, especially since `%` is more like a units-designation.

For example, I would have expected `50-30%` to be either one of these:

- `(50 - 0.3) = 49.3`
- `(50 - 30) / 100 = 0.20`

...but what you're asking for sounds stranger still: `50 * (1 - 0.3) = 35`.

That opens up additional weirdness. Wouldn't both of these be true?

- `0+5%` would become `0 * (1 + 0.05) = 0`
- `5%` would become `5 / 100 = 0.05`

This is odd because adding zero usually doesn't change what the number means.

---

## A more-restrictive version

OK, what about allowing percentage-based changes only if the user avoids ambiguity? One way would be to create new binary operators like `A -% B` or `A +% B`, but that's not quite human-centric, so how about:

```
expr: e EOF ;

e
 : SUB e                          
 | parenExpr
 | percentOp        
 | binaryOp
 | FLT                             
 ;
parenExpr
 : LPAREN e RPAREN
 ;
percentOp
 : (FLT|parenExpr) (ADD|SUB) (FLT|parenExpr) PCT
 ;
binaryOp
 : e (ADD|SUB|MUL|DIV) e
 ;

PCT : '%';
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';
ADD :  '+' ;
SUB :  '-' ;
MUL :  '*' ;
DIV :  '/' ;
FLT: [0-9]+(('.'|',')[0-9]+)?;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
WS : [ \t\n]+ -> skip ;
```

This would mean:

- `50-5-4%` is treated as `100-(5-4%)` to get 45.2.
- `5%` is not valid (on its own)
- `5%+4` is not valid

Comment: Everything you wrote is correct (except that i think that this behavior isn't that confusing :). What would you answer if someone asks you "How much is 50$ minus 30%" ?

Comment: It only works because the human is inferring that you mean "fifty dollars minus thirty percent [of fifty dollars]", and nobody even *tries* to use complex variations. For example, "5 percent plus twenty minus 50 percent plus 30 plus 20 percent" rapidly becomes ambiguous.

Comment: @johnbaum I'd recommend restricting the special-percentage behavior to force people to keep it simple. Something to eliminate the potential for crazy edge cases like `5%-100+20%-10%+2-5%` by forcing people to either deal with floats or to add explicit parentheses.

Comment: @johnbaum One other thing to think about: If the system ever allows someone to write `(10)*(5%)` and outputs `0.5`, wouldn't the user then, quite logically, expect `(10)-(5%)` to follow the same rules and be `9.95`? If you want the second case to be `9.5`, then you're basically giving strange new meaning to parenthesis.

Comment: I meant to highlight the parts that are interpreted as "intelligent" percentage expression in some way to clarify the special handling. Treating `5%` as not valid is no viable alternative. But your suggestion about restricting the special-percentage behavior sounds sensible. I will have to think about a reasonable tradeoff.

Comment: @johnbaum OK, one more "what if" scenario here to worry about: The confusion between the *basis* a percentage is on, and it happens quite a bit even in person-to-person communication: If someone says `120 +10% -10%`, does that come out to `120`, or does it come out to `(120 * 1.1 * 0.9)=118.8`? Hopefully this'll never come up for restaurant-tips, but I can imagine it happening for some retail sales-events and such.